# Getting items to align to the left on navbar collapse (in Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to have a nav-bar where the items align to the right by default, but on nav-bar collapse, they align to the left.

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid" width='300px'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/UWCL_logo_white.png" alt="Gibbs Lab" style="width:80px;height:auto;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left " id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navText " style='list-style-type: square'>
                <li ><a class="dropdown-divider" href="production/index.html" id="navText">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="research/index.html" id="navText">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="education/index.html" id="navText">Data Dashboards</a></li>
                <li><a href="people/index.html" id="navText">Current Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Here's the way my nav-bar looks

[image]

And, when collapsed:

[image]

How can I get those items (in the second picture) to align to the left of the page?  I've tried the following, with no luck:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: can you provide snippet?

Comment: why you are not using bootstrap `navbar` code in your code? for more info visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap 3 markup

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your *ul* tag : `mr-auto`